# Why MySQL does not use UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql

Why MySQL in first case uses UNIQUE KEY but in second case doesn't?

First case:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date < '2019-08-13 23:00:31';
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE_NAME           | range | log_index     | log_index | 8       | NULL | 76359 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Second case:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date < '2019-08-14 23:00:31';
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE_NAME           | ALL  | log_index     | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 556312 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table description:

```
mysql> show create table TABLE_NAME;
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_NAME | CREATE TABLE `TABLE_NAME` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `depth` double NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `log_index` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=556313 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table min max date:

```
mysql> select max(date), min(date) from TABLE_NAME;
+---------------------+---------------------+
| max(date)           | min(date)           |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-09-11 05:09:15 | 2019-08-09 23:00:31 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This text is to avoid problem with: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: How many rows are there that are < 2019-08-13 23:00:31 and how many are < 2019-08-14 23:00:31? Looks like there are too many rows between these two dates.

Comment: mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date > '2019-08-13 23:00:31' AND date <  '2019-08-14 23:00:31';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    17273 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

Comment: The same like between 2019-08-12 and 2019-08-13